# Anonymous class with interface

Tags: java, interface, anonymous-function, inner-classes

I am confused about the concept of interface when dealing with anonymous inner class. As far as I know that you can't instantiate an interface in Java, so the following statement would have a compile error

```
     ActionListener action = new ActionListener();  // compile error
```

What happen when it deals with anonymous class? why does it allow to use `new`? For example:

```
     JButton button = new JButton("A");
     button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){    //this is fine
           @Override
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

           }
     };
```

Does the compiler just make a class and implement `ActionListener` behind the scene? How does it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It allows you to create a new anonymous class that implements `ActionListener` because you're providing the implementation, you're just not giving it a class name.

Comment: So what instance are we actually creating ?

Comment: @user1389813 The instance that you're passing to the `addActionListener` method.  It doesn't really need an explicitly-declared type because you're never going to use it again.  The compiler just fills in some placeholder name.  It's just the class that implements `ActionListener` with the override that you defined inline.  It's still safe to say that it IS-A `ActionListener`, since that's what the reference type would be.

Comment: a new anonymous inner class object that implements ActionListener. with anonymous inner classes, it is obvious that you will be implementing some interface, so i feel the implements keyword is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

When you create an inner-class, you are instantiating an anonymous class that implements the interface.

In your case, The effect is the same of: `public class Foo implements ActionListener`

Answer (score 1):

You're defining an inner class with a sequentially assigned name like `1`, `2`, `3` etc. At the same time you're instantiating the inner class with the `new` keyword. You don't care about the name of the inner class because you're using it anonymously. If you look in your bin directory you'll see a class file for each of the anonymous definitions. For example if you used an anonymous class in a class, `Foo`, you would have `Foo.class` and `Foo$1.class` created for you. I believe this means that you could instantiate more of the anonymous classes at a later date using reflection.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a class and implementing the interface when working with anonymous class.you can override the methods or implement the method inside the anonymous class

```
    A a= new A(){ 

               };
```

Here a is a reference variable of type A which is referring not to A but to an object of class which implement A who doesn't have a name